# Importing images with react and webpack

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

I've been trying to import an image using react and webpack however I haven't been successful yet.. I already installed file-loader and url-loader using npm, I already configured the webpack.config file as I saw it on the docs however I just get an error..
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vdSpLwgwJgUuBCKjej_QosJazMaiGe7P

thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you placed the image minor.png in same same folder of 'SearchBar' file?

Comment: please can you check https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0):

Instead write like this in your SearchBar component.

```
import Minor from './minor.png'

class SearchBar extends component{
 render(){
  return(
     <img src={Minor} alt="myLogo" />
  )
 }
}
```

Comment: I actually tried to did it as you told me and I get the exact same error!

Comment: yess.. these are the screenshots of the searchbar component as well of my webpack.config https://drive.google.com/open?id=1D_TjRMB1NW81WpkY207u3kMHfdMjaYY-